# Flutter Debug - "Exception: Build process failed."

Tags: c++, flutter, dart

I'm trying to build a flutter project for the Windows platform. When I execute `flutter run`, the only output I get in the terminal is `Exception: Build process failed.`. How can I get more information on the error message to debug the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- flutter pub cache clean
- flutter clean
- flutter pub cache repair
- flutter pub get

Check your Flutter and Dart SDK versions: flutter doctor

Check for any specific error messages: flutter run -v

Comment: Thank you - flutter run -v was what I was looking for!